# Why does `readLines` close a ZipInputStream?

Tags: groovy

In Groovy (v2.4.1), I'm trying to read the contents of the files within a zipped file,

```
import java.util.zip.*

ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("d:\\temp\\small.zip"))

while (zipEntry = zis.nextEntry) {
    println "Reading ${zipEntry.name}..."
    def filedata = zis.readLines()
    println filedata
}
```

gives the following error after reading the first file in the zip,

`java.io.IOException: Stream closed`

Why does that happen? It is same with `eachLine` and `getText` too ( haven't tried any other methods in `InputStream`) How can I read all the zip file contents from a `ZipInputStream` in `groovy`?

**Update:**
Though I've used a file as an example above, I actually only have an `InputStream` and not a physical file

Comment: The assumption with eachLine and getText is that they are dealing with the entirety of the contents, therefore closing is an appropriate simplification. In this case it is obviously inappropriate.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `zipEntry`. You're trying to read the whole zip file by doing `zis.readLines()` and not reading that particular entry.

Comment: @weston yes, I can see that now. The java implementation of `ZipInputStream.read()` reads till the end of `ZipEntry` and then you need to call `nextEntry()` to move the marker to the next file in the stream. I presumed the same in `groovy`. I was wrong.

Comment: You seem to be assuming all your zipped files are text...  is this the case?

Comment: Well `read()` does behave the same, but `readLines()` is not available in java at all, and is an extension method on `InputStream`. It's not got a special extension method for `ZipInputStream` though you could write one: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module

Comment: @tim_yates yes, they are all text files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InputStream`'s `readLines()` method is added via [this](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java) class. When you look at line no 791 you will see that `readLines()` is delegated to the overridden version with `Reader` as an argument. As it can be seen in the [docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/Reader.html#readLines()) this method closes the stream after reading it. That's why the your example fails.

Here's how it can be done:

```
import java.util.zip.*

def zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream('lol.zip'))

while (zipEntry = zis.nextEntry) {
    println "Reading $zipEntry.name"
    def output = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    output << zis
    println "Output: $output"
}
```

Comment: It still was a useful post before I say.

Comment: thanks for the links to the source code and docs. I failed to mention in the sample code that I only have an InputStream, so your solution will not work for me. but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Opal better than the buffer/while loop, is the Groovy [`eachByte`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/InputStream.html#eachByte%28int,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29) method that does this for you...

Comment: @tim_yates, good idea but can't work it out. Could you please edit or provide a gist?

Comment: @Opal [something like this](https://gist.github.com/timyates/c65da4675673fdd689a7)?

Comment: @tim_yates, with this version of `eachByte` and it's missing buffer size. I've tried exactly the same and **Stream closed**.

Comment: @Opal I'm an idiot...  that indeed [closes the stream](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/a52d0d3c5dd1cbb342992d36235171718a563c8b/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L1370) :-(

Comment: @tim_yates, you're definitely not ;)

Comment: @Opal updated the gist to use left shift, as that uses the buffer technique [under the covers](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/a52d0d3c5dd1cbb342992d36235171718a563c8b/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/IOGroovyMethods.java#L231) and so you don't need to implement it yourself :-)